# GTA V Doesn't Save Progress

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-v

I'm playing GTA V on Xbox 360, but the game is not saving my progress.
I did the mission that tells you to go to your house I got an alert telling me that I'm logged out and press "A" button to log in. When you get to choose which profile you wanna log in to save the game and you select it, it just goes back to the "alert" page that tells me that I have to log in again. So every time I wanna play GTA V I need to do all of the robbery missions and Simeon missions

Comment: That sounds odd. To check a few things: do you have an Xbox live account, or is it a local profile? Are you trying to save locally, or to the cloud? Do you have a hard drive?

Comment: one thing for me was the date. after some update from xbox360, i couldn't play until i changed the date of my console to the present. i play offline, so i switch it on, change the date then play the game. the game would then go to my save point. try to change the date to today and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

You might not have Auto-Save On. Check Settings on the in-game menu. If that's not the problem, you should check to see if you have space left on your hard drive.

It might also be your internet connection, which could keep logging you out.

Answer (score 1):

I know it sounds weird but i had this issue too and i just figured it out. You have to go into system settings and change the date on your xbox console to the current date. I promise it will fix it.

Answer (score -2):

You have not signed in. you will need to sign in to save your progress and to be awarded achievements.Do you want to sign in now?